# How effecient is indexing into an HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript, htmlcollection

According to [Nicholas Zakas](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html), among others, HTMLCollections are so slow that copying the entire thing into an array is good practice if you are going to be accessing members repeatedly. He seems to claim that even using the indexers on HTMLCollections causes the collection to completely requery the DOM for all matching elements, as if the collection is actually a linq-esq expression tree, rather than a list of pointers leading straight to the elements.

I've got a situation where I need to allow easy keyboard navigation of tables. Every time someone hits one of the arrow keys, I need to switch focus from one table cell to another, and add and remove CSS classes accordingly. I thought about just storing the HTMLCollection of table rows returned by `tableElement.rows`, and accessing the individual cell elements through it. I know that HTMLCollections allow you to index into them as if they are arrays, and I assumed that this would be just as efficient as indexing into an array. Now I'm rethinking things, but I still want to understand why.

My question is this: What exactly happens under the hood when I call `tableElement.rows[2].cells[6]`?

Comment: it has the table element, it would look up the 3th row and then inside the cells look up the 7th cell, so yes, if you have such a code in a loop, it can bring something to extract the row/cell before each next iteration. However, if you only sporadicly interact with the tableElement, you shouldn't really worry about lost performance on that level ;)

Comment: This SitePoint article may help explain how JavaScript's native HTMLCollection differs from DOM element arrays generated by jQuery: [JavaScript vs jQuery HTML Collections](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-vs-jquery-html-collections/)

Comment: The most relevant excerpt from said article: "`HTMLCollection` objects are *live*. They are automatically updated whenever the underlying document changes. jQuery and most other JavaScript libraries use methods such as `document.getElementsByTagName()` but copy the resulting nodes to a real array. Therefore, it’s a query on the state of the document *at that time*: it is never updated."

Comment: @Icepickle -- That's a fair point. I guess I was just wondering whether indexing into tableElement.rows is constant time (i.e. following a pointer directly to the element), or if it's linear (i.e. the HTMLCollection is just an expression tree, and indexing triggers a search through the DOM for the matching element). The question was triggered more by curiosity than by necessity.